# Laravel Apply middlware on specific route of resource route controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware, laravel-resource

I want to apply middleware on create route of resource controller but confused how to set middleware. Normally we can add middleware like this

```
Route::get('api/users/{user}', function (App\Models\User $user) {
    return $user->email;
})->middleware('name');
```

but when we have a resource controller so how could I apply middleware on single route of resource controller.

```
Route::resource('front-pages','Admin\FrontPagesController');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a `__construct()` function

in FrontPagesController.php

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index','show']]);
}
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#controller-middleware

---

all the possible functions

```php
/**
 * Instantiate a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');

    $this->middleware('log')->only('index');

    $this->middleware('subscribed')->except('store');
}
```

Comment: Can I also pass only instead of except ??

Comment: Yes you can do anything

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::middleware('name')->resource('front-pages' , 'Admin\FrontPagesController');
```

refer laravel documentation :https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#introduction

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
 Route::resource('front-pages','Admin\FrontPagesController')->only('fornt-page.whatever name');
```

And you can group it with middleware